# Appending to Dictionary: Preventing Duplicates in both key and value

Tags: python, dictionary

```
temp_dict = dict()
for i in df['Incident_Type'].unique():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
    col2 = []
    col3 = []
    for j in df['Incident_Type'].unique():
        if i!=j:
            v = nlp(i).similarity(nlp(j))
            col2.append(j)
            col3.append(v)
        else:
            continue
    idx = col3.index(np.max(col3))
    temp_dict[i] = col2[idx]
```

In the above code, in temp_dict, the values are appended as:{A:B,B:A}. As A and B are already compared and appended, how can I prevent comparing and appending of B:A

One more thing, if while comparing A:B, B:C, if B:C are found more closely related to each other, we just want B:C. A will have other element more closelt related to it

Comment: You want to prevent adding `'B': 'A'`, if `'A': 'B'` is already in the dictionary? What if `'A': 'B'` is already in there, do you want to allow `'C': 'B'`? Or do you need values to be unique, just like keys would have to be unique? What about `'A': 'B'`, `'B': 'C'` and `'C': 'A'` all existing?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. No, just the unique ones. As it is based on similarity score as in col3: If relation of A:B is greater than C:A, we just want A:B drop C:A

Answer (score 1):

You wan't every pair of `key: item` to be unique, no matter the order of them, right? If that's case, you can do the following:

The method `dict.items()` returns a `dict_items` object, which is a `view` of dictionary `keys and items` that consists of a `tuple` for every pair of `key: item`, so you can compare the values you want to check in the `tuples` returned:

`(i, j) not in temp_dict.items()`

on your code, could be something like this:

```py
temp_dict = dict()
for i in df['Incident_Type'].unique():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
    col2 = []
    col3 = []
    for j in df['Incident_Type'].unique():
        if i!=j and (i, j) not in temp_dict.items() and (j, i) not in temp_dict.items():
            v = nlp(i).similarity(nlp(j))
            col2.append(j)
            col3.append(v)
        else:
            continue
    idx = col3.index(np.max(col3))
    temp_dict[i] = col2[idx]
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're right, thanks! I updated the answer with the correct return type

Comment: Thank you for your kind support. But it is not working for this case:if relation of A:B is greater than C:A, we just want A:B drop C:A

Answer (score 0):

With data as below I hope this could help you:

```py
import pandas as pd

#
#   S a m p l e   D a t a F r a m e   
data = [{"Incident_Type": 'A'}, {"Incident_Type": 'D'}, {"Incident_Type": 'B'}, {"Incident_Type": 'A'}, {"Incident_Type": 'C'}, {"Incident_Type": 'B'}, {"Incident_Type": 'A'},
{"Incident_Type": 'D'}, {"Incident_Type": 'X'}, {"Incident_Type": 'B'}, {"Incident_Type": 'A'}, {"Incident_Type": 'Z'}, {"Incident_Type": 'B'}, {"Incident_Type": 'A'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
print('--------------------------------------')

temp_dict = {}
temp_list = []
for i in df['Incident_Type'].unique():
    for j in df['Incident_Type'].unique():
        if i != j and i not in temp_dict.keys() and i not in temp_dict.values() and j not in temp_dict.keys() and j not in temp_dict.values():
            temp_dict[i] = j
print(temp_dict)
'''
   Incident_Type
0              A
1              D
2              B
3              A
4              C
5              B
6              A
7              D
8              X
9              B
10             A
11             Z
12             B
13             A
--------------------------------------
{'A': 'D', 'B': 'C', 'X': 'Z'}
'''
```